# I need to scrape a web with scrapy and python but I can't resolve the address to find what I want to extract

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to get the data from a job proposal page using Python in Jupyter,
the page is this: [computrabajo](https://www.computrabajo.com.pe/empleos-en-la-libertad)

I have managed to obtain the title, company and qualification using a guide but when I want to obtain the description of the proposal, the following appears:

[image: Terminal]

I think the reason is because I am not placing the route correctly or whatever it is called in the following code (DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR AND extract_first()):

```
def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.box_border'
    for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
        NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 ::text'
        EMPRESA_SELECTOR = './/p[text()]/a/text()'
        CALIFICACIÓN_SELECTOR = './/p[text()]/span/text()'
        DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR = './/p[text()]/text()'
        yield {
            'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'empresa': brickset.xpath(EMPRESA_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'calificacion': brickset.xpath(CALIFICACIÓN_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'descripcion': brickset.xpath(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        }
```

[image: Description]

This is what I want to get, if I use the extract it extracts everything, but at least I know that it is possible to extract

If it is not too much trouble, if someone knew how to save those records that I get in a csv as with beautiful soup it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `<p>` tags under your `SET_SELECTOR`.

Try using a more specific `xpath` selector like:

```
.//p[@class='fc_aux t_word_wrap mb10 hide_m']/text()
```